# Android studio how to keep the chat scrolled down to the last message?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a chat app. I want to keep chat shows the last sent messages(scrolled all the way down).

[image]

every time I reopen the chat or the keyboard shows, the messages scroll up.as shown here[image]

```
  recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
         profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

Although this line is supposed to fix the problem but it doesn't:

```
 linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, after getting/reading any new message run below code

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
```

This will scrollTo End of the message size.

Comment: is this supposed to be added in the adapter class?

Comment: It should be applied every time you gets new message. It will scrol to end forl all new messages.

Comment: No not in adaptor. Apply in chat activity.

Comment: it worked, now when I open the chat it is scrolled down and when I send a message it is also scrolled down. But when I close the keyboard it scrolls to the middle of the messages, not to the end. Do you have any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Also put it on send button. So whenever you send message it does scroll it to down on cleint device. If this not fixing try using soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setStackFromEnd(true)` or `.setReverseLayout(true)`
`setReverseLayout` reverses the order of the elements, `setStackFromEnd` sets the view to show the last element.

Comment: I'm using this  linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); but it doesn't fix it